# Moment.duration(): Get total number of days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to find out a readable interval duration. Here is my code with a timestamp example:

```
    let startDT = 1542621271554; // GMT: Monday, 19 November 2018 09:54:31.554
    let endDT = 1545606452513; // GMT: Sunday, 23 December 2018 23:07:32.513

    let interval = moment.duration(endDT - startDT);
    alert(
        interval.days() +
            "d" +
            interval.hours() +
            "h" +
            interval.minutes() +
            "m" +
            interval.seconds() +
            "s"
    );
```

I'm getting as the following result: `3d13h13m0s`

I expected to get the total number of days of the interval (not considering months or years). In my example, `34d13h13m0s`

How I accomplish that ?

Comment: Have you tried [`interval.asDays()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/ "Moment.js | Docs")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use moment.js's [`duration().asDays()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/) function. `Math.floor` removes the partial day (hours, minutes and seconds) from the duration.

```js
let startDT = 1542621271554; // GMT: Monday, 19 November 2018 09:54:31.554
let endDT = 1545606452513; // GMT: Sunday, 23 December 2018 23:07:32.513

let interval = moment.duration(endDT - startDT);
alert(
  Math.floor(interval.asDays()) +
  "d" +
  interval.hours() +
  "h" +
  interval.minutes() +
  "m" +
  interval.seconds() +
  "s"
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it without moment:

```js
let startDT = 1542621271554;
let endDT = 1545606452513;
let daysDiff = parseInt( (endDT-startDT) / (24*60*60*1000) );
console.log('Days:', daysDiff);
alert('Days: '+daysDiff);
```

Comment: That _only_ gets the days, however.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in your comments, simply use asDays or calculate it manually as another answer has mentioned.  This question shows the absolute minimum effort to come up with the answer yourself.

```js
let startDT = 1542621271554; // GMT: Monday, 19 November 2018 09:54:31.554
let endDT = 1545606452513; // GMT: Sunday, 23 December 2018 23:07:32.513

let interval = moment.duration(endDT - startDT);
alert(
    interval.asDays()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```